Ffmpeg image command equivalence
I need help on getting the right and equivalent command to:
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i input.png -i audio.m4a -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv

I’m currently using:
ffmpeg -lavfi "color=black:1920x1080, drawtext=text='Example' :fontsize=h/8 :fontcolor=white :x=(w-tw)/2 :y=(h-th)/2" -frames 1 out.png

Is there image encoding command that will be equivalent to:
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i input.png -i audio.m4a -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv


What do you exactlly mean with image equivalent do you want to mix an audio with an image?

I want to create an image this command: ffmpeg -lavfi "color=black:1920x1080, drawtext=text='Example' :fontsize=h/8 :fontcolor=white :x=(w-tw)/2 :y=(h-th)/2" -frames 1 out.png to something similar to this command: ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i input.png -i audio.m4a -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv

To combine two commands and turn it into one command creating a video like this: ffmpeg -lavfi "color=black:1920x1080, drawtext=text='Example' :fontsize=h/8 :fontcolor=white :x=(w-tw)/2 :y=(h-th)/2" -frames 1 out.png ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i input.png -i audio.m4a -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv

combine both making mkv file like the one I’ve shown?

You want to create an image with color filter + audio in one command right? Please take a look at my answer.

You can use more than 1 input in the command to join the image created with color and the audio you already have, the first input is refeered as 0 and the second as 1 and so on in the -map part use first input's video -map 0:v, use second's input audio -map 1:a:
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "color=black:1920x1080:r=1, drawtext=text='Example' :fontsize=h/8 :fontcolor=white :x=(w-tw)/2 :y=(h-th)/2" -i "01. Training Season.mp3" -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv

